# MVC: Pass ViewData object with type 'double' to number input field

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, input

I’m trying to pass a ViewData object of type double to an input field of type number with 1 decimal place. But the input field keeps empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
<p>
   Debiet factor: <input name="FlowFact" type="number" value="@ViewData["FlowFact"]"  step="0.1" autocomplete="off">
   @String.Format("{0:N1} m³/h", @ViewData["FlowFact"]) <!--Result = 3,1 m³/h-->
</p>
```

Comment: if the input field is empty then there is probably nothing in the `ViewData["FlowFact"]`. Make sure you don't have a typo

Comment: I've added the @String.Format... line to check if there is a value in the ViewData object. And there is a value 3,1 in it.
I don't see any typo's in the code above.

Comment: It's because you `input` type is `number` and you're trying to pass it a value of `3,1` and it's not accepting  that as a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to jamiedanq.

In my controller I was writing a double value to the @ViewData["FlowFact"] object. But in my view it was returning a value 3,0999 , which is not a correct value for the input type 'Number' because of the ",".

Instead of passing a double value to the object I've changed it to pass a string value and replace the "," with a ".":

Controller:

```js
@ViewData["FlowFact"] = @String.Format("{0:N1}", MyDoubleValue).Replace(",",".");
```

View:

```html
<p>
   Debiet factor: <input name="FlowFact" type="number" value="@ViewData["FlowFact"]"  step="0.1" autocomplete="off">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is what the `ViewData["FlowFact"]` is returning, which according to your `@String.Format("{0:N1} m³/h", @ViewData["FlowFact"]) <!--Result = 3,1 m³/h-->` it's `3,1`.

That is not recognised as a number so it won't work. Either return a whole number or a decimal number. So instead of a `3,1`, return a `3.1` or just a `3`.
Otherwise change the input type to accept what you are passing.

Comment: Thanks, so will it work like this:
@ViewData["FlowFact"])  = Convert.ToDecimal(MyDoubleValue)
Which than probably gives me 3.1 instead of 3,1?

Comment: `3,1` is not a double value, it's `string`. You'll need to pass the actual `double` value the input type number or make your input type accept the string you are passing

Comment: So @ViewData["FlowFact"] is returns a string value 3,1?

Comment: @JeroenSterkens please check what you're passing to the `ViewData` and let me know or include that code in your question